# How to remove duplicate object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have object like this :

```
cons data = []
const result =
[
    {
        "result_id": "AAA877",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAA877",
                "hashtag_id": 1,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NodeJs",
                    "hashtag_group_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAAAA1",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAAAA1",
                "hashtag_id": 1,
                "apptype_id": 4,
                "tag": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NodeJs",
                    "hashtag_group_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAB238",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAB238",
                "hashtag_id": 2,
                "apptype_id": 4,
                "tag": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAB415",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAB415",
                "hashtag_id": 1,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NodeJs",
                    "hashtag_group_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAD668",
        "emp_id": 2,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAD668",
                "hashtag_id": 1,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NodeJs",
                    "hashtag_group_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAG239",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAG239",
                "hashtag_id": 4,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAH740",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAH740",
                "hashtag_id": 2,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAK119",
        "emp_id": 2,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAK119",
                "hashtag_id": 1,
                "apptype_id": 4,
                "tag": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "NodeJs",
                    "hashtag_group_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "result_id": "AAK298",
        "emp_id": 1,
        "hashtag": [
            {
                "result_id": "AAK298",
                "hashtag_id": 2,
                "apptype_id": 3,
                "tag": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to filter and push `emp_id` and `apptype_id` without a duplicate

This is what i expected :

```
[
  { emp_id: 1, app_type_id: 3 },
  { emp_id: 1, app_type_id: 4 },
  { emp_id: 2, app_type_id: 3 },
  { emp_id: 2, app_type_id: 4 }
]
```

I was trying like this :

```
result.forEach(r => {
        if (r.hashtag[0].tag !== null) {
          const t = {
            emp_id: r.emp_id,
            app_type_id: r.hashtag[0].apptype_id
          }
          if (data.indexOf(t) === -1) {
            data.push(t)
          }
        }
      })
```

But what i got was like this :

```
[
  { emp_id: 1, app_type_id: 3 },
  { emp_id: 1, app_type_id: 4 },
  { emp_id: 1, app_type_id: 3 },
  { emp_id: 2, app_type_id: 3 },
  { emp_id: 2, app_type_id: 4 }
]
```

How to filter without a duplicate like what i expected ?

Please ask me if you need more information if it's still not enough

Comment: Have you tried [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Will `hashtag` always only have one object in its array?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't try .filter() yet @ZainWilson-WCHStudent

Comment: yes, ```hashtag``` will always have one object in array @Andy

Comment: Assuming the `hashtag` array always has one item in it, I would approach this with `Array.reduce` method. That is, create a new array by `reduce` method that organizes the data by `emp_id`, then build a final result array by `map` that massages the output.

Comment: @user18605090 Here is the MDN for [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach. Loop over the data, [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties you want into a new object, [stringify that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and push that string into a temporary array. Then, on every next iteration, check to see if that string has already been created. If it hasn't push that string into the array.

Finally [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the strings and [parse each one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to produce an array of objects that matches your expected output.

```js
const data=[{result_id:"AAA877",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAA877",hashtag_id:1,apptype_id:3,tag:{id:1,name:"NodeJs",hashtag_group_id:1}}]},{result_id:"AAAAA1",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAAAA1",hashtag_id:1,apptype_id:4,tag:{id:1,name:"NodeJs",hashtag_group_id:1}}]},{result_id:"AAB238",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAB238",hashtag_id:2,apptype_id:4,tag:null}]},{result_id:"AAB415",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAB415",hashtag_id:1,apptype_id:3,tag:{id:1,name:"NodeJs",hashtag_group_id:1}}]},{result_id:"AAD668",emp_id:2,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAD668",hashtag_id:1,apptype_id:3,tag:{id:1,name:"NodeJs",hashtag_group_id:1}}]},{result_id:"AAG239",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAG239",hashtag_id:4,apptype_id:3,tag:null}]},{result_id:"AAH740",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAH740",hashtag_id:2,apptype_id:3,tag:null}]},{result_id:"AAK119",emp_id:2,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAK119",hashtag_id:1,apptype_id:4,tag:{id:1,name:"NodeJs",hashtag_group_id:1}}]},{result_id:"AAK298",emp_id:1,hashtag:[{result_id:"AAK298",hashtag_id:2,apptype_id:3,tag:null}]}];

const temp = [];

for (const obj of data) {
  const { emp_id, hashtag: [{ apptype_id }] } = obj;
  const newObj = { emp_id, app_type_id: apptype_id };
  const str = JSON.stringify(newObj);
  if (!temp.includes(str)) temp.push(str);
}

const out = temp.map(str => JSON.parse(str));
console.log(out);
```

Comment: I think that even without stringifying the object it would work since it would compare the memory address. This solution assumes that there's only one element inside the hastag array, if there's more than one  ( since it's an array it's a legit assumption ) it would need some extra tweaks.

Comment: @CesarePolonara OP already told me that `hashtag` would only have one object (see comments).

Comment: Ok sorry, I  missed it !

Answer (score 0):

I would run a filter on the objects that you have before extracting the info! This should do the trick:

```
var removed_duplicates = result.filter((result, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex((other_entry) => 
        (other_entry.emp_id === result.emp_id && 
         other_entry.hashtag[0].apptype_id === result.hashtag[0].apptype_id)))
```

What this does is it filters your original entries by looking for other entries in the list with the same values that you're trying to filter on. If there are none, then the returned index will be the same, otherwise it will succeed for the first encounter with one of the duplicate entries but fail for all of the following ones, causing them to be removed.

Comment: thanks for answering my question! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could get an array of objects and filter with a `Set`.

```js
const
    data = [{ result_id: "AAA877", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAA877", hashtag_id: 1, apptype_id: 3, tag: { id: 1, name: "NodeJs", hashtag_group_id: 1 } }] }, { result_id: "AAAAA1", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAAAA1", hashtag_id: 1, apptype_id: 4, tag: { id: 1, name: "NodeJs", hashtag_group_id: 1 } }] }, { result_id: "AAB238", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAB238", hashtag_id: 2, apptype_id: 4, tag: null }] }, { result_id: "AAB415", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAB415", hashtag_id: 1, apptype_id: 3, tag: { id: 1, name: "NodeJs", hashtag_group_id: 1 } }] }, { result_id: "AAD668", emp_id: 2, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAD668", hashtag_id: 1, apptype_id: 3, tag: { id: 1, name: "NodeJs", hashtag_group_id: 1 } }] }, { result_id: "AAG239", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAG239", hashtag_id: 4, apptype_id: 3, tag: null }] }, { result_id: "AAH740", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAH740", hashtag_id: 2, apptype_id: 3, tag: null }] }, { result_id: "AAK119", emp_id: 2, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAK119", hashtag_id: 1, apptype_id: 4, tag: { id: 1, name: "NodeJs", hashtag_group_id: 1 } }] }, { result_id: "AAK298", emp_id: 1, hashtag: [{ result_id: "AAK298", hashtag_id: 2, apptype_id: 3, tag: null }] }],
    result = data
        .flatMap(({ emp_id, hashtag }) => hashtag.map(({ apptype_id }) => ({ emp_id, apptype_id })))
        .filter((s => ({ emp_id, apptype_id }) => {
            const key = [emp_id, apptype_id].join('|');
            if (!s.has(key)) return s.add(key);
        })(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question! :D

Answer (score -1):

There is no structure comparison in JS, objects are compared by their "addresses in memory", you have to compare primitive values (`[].indexOf(t)` compares items of array with `t`).

```
console.log({text: 'hey'} !== {text: 'hey'})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness